# Solving an equation including $e^{-x}$ with the Lambert W function

Tags: calculus, functions, transcendental-equations

Given two functions of $x$, namely $f(x)$ and $g(x)$, where $$f(x)=x^2-4x+8$$$$g(x)=3xe^{-x}$$ the shortest distance between the graphs of the functions is sought.

I begin by defining a function $h(x)$ which returns the vertical distance between the functions, $h(x)=f(x)-g(x)$.

Then I locate the global minimum by solving $h'(x)=0$, which I solve numerically and get $x\approx 1.802$, which is what I wanted.

However, I wish to solve this algebraically. The equation $h'(x)=0$ is $$3xe^{-x}-3e^{-x}+2x-4=0$$

My first instinct is to isolate the equation in the form $a=be^b$, with $a$ as a constant term, and then use the Lambert W function to solve for $x$.

Is it possible to isolate the terms in such a way, or do I have a transcendental equation? What does this mean in terms of the number of real solutions and how should I go about approximating the solution from this point?

Comment: i have no hope to solve this in an analytically way

Comment: @Asapzai: Careful: "Shortest distance between the graphs of the functions" and "shortest $\mathit{vertical}$ distance between the graphs of the functions" are not the same thing...

Comment: @Galidakis I guess that the values are equivalent in this case, but it's my bad for using them interchangeably.

Comment: For what it's worth, in recent years calculus books have been including problems such as this that are intended to be solved approximately with a standard graphing calculator (e.g. the TI-82 and its descendents) without specifically saying that such a device is intended to be used. These problems began showing up in the early 1990s, and back then there would be explicit comments in the text saying that a graphing calculator was intended, but I think with the now omnipresence of graphing calculators, books have been less explicit about when they might be needed.

Answer (score 0):

$$h'(x)=3xe^{-x}-3e^{-x}+2x-4=0\implies e^{-x}=-\frac 23\,\frac{ x-2}{ x-1} $$ and the solution is given in terms  of the [generalized Lambert function](https://arxiv.org/abs/1408.3999) (have a look at equation $(4)$).

Answer (score -1):

$h(x) = f(x)-g(x) = x^2-4x+8-3xe^{-x}$

$y=min\{h(x) , x \in \mathbb{R} \}$

Now note that $h'(x)=2x-4-3e^{-x}+3xe^{-x}=2(x-2)+3e^{-x}(x-1)$

$h'(x) = 2(x-2)+3(x-1)*e^{-x}=0$ gives $2*e^{x}(x-2)+3(x-1)=0$, cause $ e^{x}\not=0$. Solving this equation is not easy, but if you want to do this I would also suggest using the Lambert equation.